# Excel - String Remove Duplicates

Tags: regex, string, excel, vba, duplicates

I am working with some UK address data which within an Excel cell is split into its constituent parts by a comma.

I have some VBA which I've taken from the web which has removed a number of exact duplicated entries but I am left with a large amount of data which has repeating segments some sequentially and some non sequentially.

Attached is an image highlighting what I am trying to achieve, the code I have used thus far which is not mine is included to show you the direction in which I have been looking.  Anyone have any further thoughts on how this can be achieved?

```
Function stringOfUniques(inputString As String, delimiter As String)
Dim xVal As Variant
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each xVal In Split(inputString, delimiter)
dict(xVal) = xVal
Next xVal

stringOfUniques = Join(dict.Keys(), ",")
End Function
```

This did manage to get rid of a number of them but there is a huge population that I am working on so automating this would be incredible.

[image: Ideal Outcome]

Comment: A RegExp with back-references would be another possible option

Answer (score 4):

Possibly not the most elegant answer, but this does the trick.
Here I use the Split command to split the string at each comma.
The result returned from this is

```
bat ball banana
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub test()
 Dim Mystring As String
 Dim StrResult As String

 Mystring = "bat,ball,bat,ball,banana"
 StrResult = shed_duplicates(Mystring)
End Sub
Private Function shed_duplicates(ByRef Mystring As String) As String
 Dim MySplitz() As String
 Dim J As Integer
 Dim K As Integer
 Dim BooMatch As Boolean
 Dim StrTemp(10) As String ' assumes no more than 10 possible splits!
 Dim StrResult As String


 MySplitz = Split(Mystring, ",")
  For J = 0 To UBound(MySplitz)
     BooMatch = False
     For K = 0 To UBound(StrTemp)
         If MySplitz(J) = StrTemp(K) Then
            BooMatch = True
            Exit For
         End If
     Next K
    If Not BooMatch Then
       StrTemp(J) = MySplitz(J)
    End If
Next
For J = 0 To UBound(StrTemp)
   If Len(StrTemp(J)) > 0 Then ' ignore blank entries
      StrResult = StrResult + StrTemp(J) + " "
   End If
Next J
Debug.Print StrResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You may really use a regex replacement:

```
^(\d*\s*([^,]*),.*)\2(,|$)
```

The replacement pattern is

```
$1$3
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY3lC0/2). The **pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of a string (or of a line if `.MultiLine = True`)
- `(\d*\s*([^,]*),.*)` - Group 1 (later referenced to with `$1` backreference from the replacement pattern) matching:

  - `\d*` - 0+ digits followed with
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespace characters
  - `([^,]*)` - Group 2 (later we can use `\2` in-pattern backreference to refer to the value captured with this subpattern) matching 0+ characters other than a comma
  - `,.*` - a comma followed with 0+ characters other than a newline
- `\2` - the text captured by Group 2
- `(,|$)` - Group 3 (later referenced to with `$3` from the replacement pattern - to restore the comma) matching either a comma or the end of string (or line if `.MultiLine = True`).

**NOTE**: You do not need `.MultiLine = True` if you just check individual cells with containing one address.

Below is a sample VBA Sub showing how this can be used in VBA:

```
Sub test()
  Dim regEx As Object
  Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  With regEx
      .pattern = "^(\d*\s*([^,]*),.*)\2(,|$)"
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = True ' Remove if individual addresses are matched
  End With
  s = "66 LAUSANNE ROAD,LAUSANNE ROAD,HORNSEY" & vbCrLf & _
      "9 CARNELL LANE,CARNELL LANE,FERNWOOD" & vbCrLf & _
      "35 FLAT ANDERSON HEIGHTS,1001 LONDON ROAD,FLAT ANDERSON HEIGHTS" & vbCrLf & _
      "27 RUSSELL BANK ROAD,RUSSEL BANK,SUTTON COLDFIELD"
  MsgBox regEx.Replace(s, "$1$3")
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Great job! Would note that a small tweak to remove doubled up commas post the regex replace would be worthwhile.

Comment: I had never ever seen the regex function, exemplary solution!

Answer (score 1):

A first solution would be to use a dictionary to get a list of unique segments.
It would then be as simple as skipping the first address number before splitting the segments:

```
Function RemoveDuplicates1(text As String) As String
  Static dict As Object
  If dict Is Nothing Then
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1  ' set the case sensitivity to All
  Else
    dict.RemoveAll
  End If

  ' Get the position just after the address number
  Dim c&, istart&, segment
  For istart = 1 To Len(text)
    c = Asc(Mid$(text, istart, 1))
    If (c < 48 Or c > 57) And c <> 32 Then Exit For  ' if not [0-9 ]
  Next

  ' Split the segments and add each one of them to the dictionary. No need to keep 
  ' a reference to each segment since the keys are returned by order of insertion.
  For Each segment In Split(Mid$(text, istart), ",")
    If Len(segment) Then dict(segment) = Empty
  Next

  ' Return the address number and the segments by joining the keys
  RemoveDuplicates1 = Mid$(text, 1, istart - 1) & Join(dict.keys(), ",")
End Function
```

A second solution would be to extract all the segments and then search if each one of them is present at a previous position:

```
Function RemoveDuplicates2(text As String) As String
  Dim c&, segments$, segment$, length&, ifirst&, istart&, iend&

  ' Get the position just after the address number
  For ifirst = 1 To Len(text)
    c = Asc(Mid$(text, ifirst, 1))
    If (c < 48 Or c > 57) And c <> 32 Then Exit For  ' if not [0-9 ]
  Next

  ' Get the segments without the address number and add a leading/trailing comma
  segments = "," & Mid$(text, ifirst) & ","
  istart = 1

  ' iterate each segment
  Do While istart < Len(segments)

    ' Get the next segment position
    iend = InStr(istart + 1, segments, ",") - 1 And &HFFFFFF
    If iend - istart Then

      ' Get the segment
      segment = Mid$(segments, istart, iend - istart + 2)

      ' Rewrite the segment if not present at a previous position
      If InStr(1, segments, segment, vbTextCompare) = istart Then
        Mid$(segments, length + 1) = segment
        length = length + Len(segment) - 1
      End If
    End If

    istart = iend + 1
  Loop

  ' Return the address number and the segments
  RemoveDuplicates2 = Mid$(text, 1, ifirst - 1) & Mid$(segments, 2, length - 1)

End Function
```

And a third solution would be to use a regular expression to remove all the duplicated segments:

```
Function RemoveDuplicates3(ByVal text As String) As String

  Static re As Object
  If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    ' Match any duplicated segment separated by a comma.
    ' The first segment is compared without the first digits.
    re.Pattern = "((^\d* *|,)([^,]+)(?=,).*),\3?(?=,|$)"
  End If

  ' Remove each matching segment
  Do While re.test(text)
    text = re.Replace(text, "$1")
  Loop

  RemoveDuplicates3 = text
End Function
```

These are the execution times for 10000 iterations (the lower the better):

```
input text  : "123 abc,,1 abc,abc 2,ABC,abc,a,c"
output text : "123 abc,1 abc,abc 2,a,c"

RemoveDuplicates1 (dictionary)  : 718 ms
RemoveDuplicates2 (text search) : 219 ms
RemoveDuplicates3 (regex)       : 1469 ms
```

Comment: Once again thank you for the multitude of elegant solutions each seems to do what I require.  Appreciated!